# Facebook share issue in Android

Tags: android, performance

I want to fix facebook share in my android app. So I used this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/ . My problem is, for first time, it worked perfectly. When i reinstall the app again, it won't run perfectly, it shows only first page after i clicking the "Login Facebook" button. please anyone help me on this.

Comment: why don't you use facebook's official sdk instead of using 3rd party liberaries

Answer (score 0):

The above tutorial uses facebook old sdk. Please don't refer that. On facebook official site they have proper tutorial with the sample code. It will be more helpful.
[start from this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)